# Why is scrolling line-by-line so much slower compared to vi-mode?

Tags: evil, scrolling

I was wondering if anyone has faced this issue before or is just me loosing my mind? It seems that `C-n` and `C-p` are so slow and sluggish compared to the `j` and `k` keys when using `evil-mode`. Is there any explanation for this or maybe some configuration that can make `C-n` and `C-p` behave similar to `j` and `k` in terms of speed.

Comment: Does the same happen with `emacs -Q` and loading up Evil manually? If not, it's your configuration.

Comment: I've never noticed a perceptible delay upon calling next-line. Are you talking about when you call it once, or when you hold down C-n and watch it scroll?

Comment: @wasamasa Yes, basically I'm on an almost barebone emacs since I'm building my config from scratch on my mac book and at the same time I'm testing evil on my linux desktop and observing these differences.

@BillO'Brien Yes, when I hold down `C-n` and scroll down.

Comment: Make the comparison on the same computer

Comment: Make the comparison on the same computer

Comment: @nega I did and still observe the same thing, unfortunately I can't upload a gif here just to make clear the difference.

Comment: Moving up/down will always be slower than left/right on the same line -- especially when scrolling up/down occurs or when calling `vertical-motion`.  As for the NS port of Emacs, the commit on 09/28/2018 (7946445962372c4255180af45cb7c857f1b0b5fa) prevents Emacs from updating the glass directly during `update_window`.  Subsequent to that commit, all the drawing on the NS port occurs when the OS calls `drawRect` and Emacs then calls `expose_frame`. Prior to 09/28/2018, the NS port could update the glass directly during `update_window` -- just like the Windows an X/X11 ports still do today.